# What is the best solution to show different styles depending on the weather in the users location?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website and Facebook application for a friend who runs a gardening services and does some handy-man servicing and would like some help to do the following;

I would not only like to do this on my Facebook application which is fairly similar to the website itself just a little more integration with Facebook, posting to wall and whatnot, but on the main website too. The reason why I have mentioned this is, as you may or may not know, one way of having an application on Facebook is to tell Facebook where the directory is and whatever on that directory on wards is shown in an iframe.

With Facebook going to my chosen directory and showing this on Facebook via an iframe, well, I don't exactly know what goes on, if they're on my website as well as Facebook or whatnot and due to being fairly new to the likes of PHP, I do apologize if this question seems a little messy but I do hope I do explain myself.

I've been told that the best option is to use HTML5 Geolocation as my primary method with a fallback to a better IP geolocator is my best option to find out their location, then I would like to check their current weather via the Met Office website ( http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/uk-3hourly-site-specific-forecast/detailed-documentation ) to then know what stylesheet should be used.

Different stylesheets are being developed for most conditions such as; Showers, Heavy Rain, Overcast, Sunny, Snow and so on until they are all developed to customize the experience for the user and to also show different div's depending on their weather and show them their forecast. An example of a div could be; if it's snowing, it would ask them if they would want any snow to be ploughed.

Lastly, something I should have also asked and mentioned earlier, I would also like this feature to work for UK users to avoid any confusion and if it is possible to see how far the user is from where they are based as he has only told me he'll do up to a 100 mile radius and if it helps him pay for his bills and whatnot he'll go there, but is there a way to check how far away they are for a contact form or to show on screen or whatnot.

Summary:

> Show different graphics depending on their location's weather and to see how far they are away from the base and show their weather forecast and if possible to change the weather upon the 3 hourly update.
>   Inform non-UK users that this is a UK only business and it would cost too much to go there.

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: Interesting. I did a bit of digging. The API you want to use requires you to tell them a location ID. They have an API to get _all_ locations, but you can't search by the user's longitude/latitude. So you would need to download the entire list, and compare the user's long/lat to every single one of the results to see which is closest. Then do the weather lookup. All of this done after the initial geolocation check.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using the IP address of your visitor, then tracing down the location of the user. After the location is found out, use any weather report server like Google to get the weather of that location. Using the value returned by the provider, you can use the server side script to change the layout or contents of the page.

It can be a hassle, and might reduce the page load time due to extended time taken to contact and wait for response from the weather report provider.

PS: Suggestions and improvements expected.